# Show that a sequence in a normed space is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Show that $(x_{k})$ a sequence in a normed space is bounded if and only if there exists a number $c$ such that $||x_{k}||<c$  for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$

The definitions to use are the following:

1. A sequence in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is a function $X: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$
2. It is said that $(x_{k})$ is bounded when there is a ball that contains all the terms of $(x_{k})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It is said that $(x_k)$ is bounded when there is a ball that contains all the terms of $(x_k)$"

That just means, that all values are in a ball $B_r(y)$, where $r$ is the radius and $y$ is the middle point. If you take $c=r+\|y\|$, then you get what you wanted, since
$$ \|x_k\|=\|x_k-y+y\| \leq \|x_k-y\| + \|y\| \leq r + \|y\| $$
holds. The other direction is trivial, since you can take the ball $B_c(0)$.

Comment: in the other direction then would it be like this?
Let $(x_{k})$ be a sequence in the normed space such that $||x_{k}||<c$, where $c> 0$, then we can consider a ball $B(0, c)$ such that for all $x_{k} \in \mathbb{R^n}$ we will have: $d(x_{k},0)=|x_{k} -0|=|x_{k}|<c$ this $(x_{k}) \subseteq B(0,c)$

Comment: yes, that is right

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! =)